# CUDA SHA-Calculation fails

Tags: c++, c, cuda

I want to write a SHA1-Function in CUDA, but when I execute the function, I get wrong results out of the function. When I run the same function on the CPU, I get correct results. My SHA-Function looks like:

```
__device__ void  SHA1_CUDA(uint8_t input_string[], int slen, uint32_t Hash_ptr[])
{
    printf("Input string is %s, input len is %d\n", input_string, slen);
    uint32_t K[80];
    uint32_t A,B,C,D,E,TEMP;
    int r,k,ln,t,l,i,j;

    Hash_ptr[0]=0x67452301;
    Hash_ptr[1]=0xefcdab89;
    Hash_ptr[2]=0x98badcfe;
    Hash_ptr[3]=0x10325476;
    Hash_ptr[4]=0xc3d2e1f0;

    ln=slen;
    r = (int)((ln+1)/64);

    if (((ln+1) % 64) > 56)
        {
        r=r+1;
        }

    // initialize Constants

    for(t=0; t<80; t++)
        {
            if (t<20)
                {
                    K[t] = 0x5a827999;
                }

            if ((t>19)&(t<40))
                {
                    K[t] = 0x6ED9EBA1;
                }
            if ((t>39)&(t<60))
                {
                    K[t] = 0x8F1BBCDC;
                }
            if (t>59)
                {
                    K[t] = 0xca62c1d6;
                }
        }

    for(l=0; l <= r; l++)
    {
        uint32_t W[80]={0};
        //Initialize Text
        for (i=0; i<16; i++)
            {
            for(j=0; j<4; j++)
                {
                    if (4*i+j <= ln)
                    {
                        k = input_string[64*l+4*i+j];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        k =0;
                    }

                    if (k<0)
                    {
                        k = k +256;
                    }

                    if (4*i+j == ln)
                        {
                            k = 0x80;
                        }

    //              W[i]= W[i] + k*(uint32_t)pow(256,(double)3-j);
                    W[i]= W[i] + k*expo_d[3-j];
                }
            }
        if ((W[14]==0)&(W[15]==0))
        {
            W[15]=8*slen;
        }

    // Hash Cycle


        for (t = 16; t <80; t++)
            {
                W[t] = Rol(W[t-3]^W[t-8]^W[t-14]^W[t-16],1);
            }

        A = Hash_ptr[0];
        B = Hash_ptr[1];
        C = Hash_ptr[2];
        D = Hash_ptr[3];
        E = Hash_ptr[4];


        for(t = 0; t < 80; t++)
        {
            TEMP = (Rol(A,5) + f(B,C,D,t) + E + W[t] + K[t]);
            E = D;
            D = C;
            C = Rol(B,30);
            B = A;
            A = TEMP;
        }

        Hash_ptr[0] = Hash_ptr[0] + A;
        Hash_ptr[1] = Hash_ptr[1] + B;
        Hash_ptr[2] = Hash_ptr[2] + C;
        Hash_ptr[3] = Hash_ptr[3] + D;
        Hash_ptr[4] = Hash_ptr[4] + E;

        ln = ln - 64;
    }

}
```

(host function is analogous, only with `__host__` instead of `__device__`).
My kernel function is

```
__global__ void test_sha(uint8_t pw[], int* pw_len, uint32_t H[])
{
    SHA1_CUDA(pw, *pw_len, H);
}
```

and I'm calling it like

```
printf("\nTesting SHA\n");
    uint32_t * H_h = (uint32_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint32_t)*5);
    memset(H_h, 0, sizeof(uint32_t) * 5);
    uint32_t * H_d;
    cudaMalloc(&H_d, sizeof(uint32_t)*5);
    cudaMemcpy(H_d, H_h, 5*sizeof(uint32_t), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    test_sha<<<1, 1>>>(Pass_d, Pass_len_d, H_d);
    cudaMemcpy(H_h, H_d, 5*sizeof(uint32_t), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaFree(H_d);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%x ", H_h[i]);
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Comparing to CPU:  \n");
    SHA1_CUDA_h(Pass_h, Pass_len, H_h);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%x ", H_h[i]);
    printf("\n\n");
    free(H_h);
```

So, my `printf`-function in the SHA-function tells me that everything has been transferred correctly, but nevertheless I get wrong results...
Where is my mistake?

Comment: It would be beneficial to have a minimum sized code that someone else could copy, paste, compile and run. Also, it would be good to know what are the expected outcomes and what is wrong in what you get. Finally, it would be also good for other users if you could provide a minimum of framework. "SHA" does not tell me anything apart Secure Hash Algorithm.

Comment: Code is on http://pastebin.com/h3tXSjVg. The SHA-function always returns `ce8a4602 5712ce8a 3175b9fc a8ed3174 5c8dbeee` regardless of input.

Comment: Ok, my problem was that I used a bad ROL-function... Sorry, my fault...

Comment: If you have found the mistake, you can provide an answer to your own post. This will remove it from the unanswered list and could be of benefit for other possible users. In a couple of days, you will be able to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, the ROL-function `Rol_CUDA` I was using in my function returned bad values, thus no one except me could solve the problem.
For everyone who wants to use this function: In line 51 on pastebin, there should be a `32-y`, and not a `-y`. With this correction everything works.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for a better answer including the information above?

Comment: @talonmies Sorry, I was responsible for the downvote. I have realized, though, that I mistakenly downvoted this answer. "Mistakenly" in the sense that I agree with your point of view to encourage removing unanswered posts from the unanswered list. I apologize. However, I agree with @PaperBirdMaster that @arc_lupus could have spent some more words about the issue. For example, what was wrong in the `Rol_CUDA` function and/or how fixing it.